# Google Chart APIs

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, sdk, google-charts

I Want to display graphs based on status like- Active,Bounce,Held, Unsubscribe
and Date wise graph on sent, open status and then displaying breakup of subscribers count in Map.

In Other words, creating custom Mc Dashboard for displaying this.
I Think we can do that by using "Google Chart APIs" or that can also built with Content SDK Block for graphs/Pie chart.

Just want to know the step by procedure how I can do that. Or any link to refer ?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Standard Reports and Dashboard charts isn't good enough? If you're going to use Visualforce, you can also consider <apex:chart> - see some examples [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_charting_example.htm)

Comment: @BrianMiller .. Hey thanks! but i am trying this in Marketing cloud.

Answer (score 0):

The only current option you have for analytics using a Google integration and Marketing Cloud is [Google Analytics 360](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_gai_google_analytics_integration_tracking.htm&type=5).

More information in this [Google blog post](https://www.blog.google/products/marketingplatform/360/google-analytics-360-salesforce/).